# Printing dictionary as table with header in vertical column

Tags: python, formatting, tabular

I am quite new to Python and still figuring out how to use formatting properly.
I have a bunch of data in a dictionary that I want to print as a table with headers in the left column. I did a lot of searching (not sure if the right terminology is vertical table or horizontal table) but most results I found have the header in the top row.
Using PrettyTable and others I can still print the data as

```
+-------+------+------------+
| index | type |      name  |
+-------+------+------------+
|   1   |  0   | username_1 |
|   2   |  1   | username_2 |
+-------+------+------------+
```

but I would like to invert it like so:

```
index   1            2
type    0            1
name    username_1   username_2
```

Is there a generic way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: Dataframe is auch better way to represent data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas transpose function for your dataframe.
Convert your data in pandas dataframe and then do .transpose() method.